# How to inspect an object in python?

Tags: python, pdb

Is there a way to inspect an object in `python` `pdb` so that I get NOT only all the properties but ALSO the current values? I know that one can use `pp dir(myObj)` but it doesn't show the values, only the properties names...

Comment: Have you tried `myObj.__dict__` and `var(myObj)`? You may have success with that approach.

Comment: @white I think you mean `vars()`?

Comment: @white thx - the `myObj.__dict__` solution does really work but it print all the values in one row. Is there a way to have single "property-vale" pair in a separate row? the `pp myObj.__dict__` does NOT work!

Comment: @InSync Yeah - You're right it should be `vars()`!

Comment: @InSync thx for correction. Is there a way to have single "property-vale" pair in a separate row using above methods?

Comment: You can implement a function to do the formatting, or install a library that does just that (I don't know any).

Comment: A quick and dirty way would be: `print(str(yourDict).replace(', ',',\n '))`